# Install Sharp mx-b200 on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I'm really new on Ubuntu 
I'd like to install sharp mx-b200 on ubuntu
I pluged the cable, ubuntu read it but can't find the driver

Help me please to print and scan with my sharp

Comment: Have you consulted official documentation of Sharp

Comment: in sharp web site I did not even find windows driver